# docker run: Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found

Tags: c#, docker, .net-core, console-application

I made a docker file for a .net core console app:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
LABEL author="some name"
LABEL description="some description"
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "L1_1_Console.dll" ]
```

and created an image from it called "labo1_1_console_image"

When i try to run this image with this command:

```
docker run --rm -it labo1_1_console_image
```

I get this error:

```
Could not execute because the specified command or file was not found.
Possible reasons for this include:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You intended to execute a .NET Core program, but dotnet-L1_1_Console.dll does not exist.
  * You intended to run a global tool, but a dotnet-prefixed executable with this name could not be found on the PATH.
```

I think the problem is the second one (im not sure) but i dont know how to fix this my L1_1_Console.dll file is respectivly to the docker file location /bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1 (i also have a publish folder in here with the same files)

update:

i changed docker file to this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
LABEL author="somename"
LABEL description=" some description"
ADD bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/L1_1_Console.dll L1_1_Console.dll
ADD bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/publish/L1_1_Console.runtimeconfig.json L1_1_Console.runtimeconfig.json
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "L1_1_Console.dll" ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your Dockerfile to

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1
LABEL author="some name"
LABEL description="some description"
ADD bin/Release/netcoreapp3.1/L1_1_Console.dll L1_1_Console.dll
ENTRYPOINT [ "dotnet", "L1_1_Console.dll" ]
```

The entrypoint can only see files in your docker image (unless you mount an external volume), so you need to manually add your dll file to the image before being able to run it.

Comment: Thx this helped alot, i changed a few things i changed it to the publish folder and also added the runtimeconfig.json file to fix another error